# How to convert tab seperated files into list?

Tags: linux, list, shell, file, type-conversion

I have a tab separated file as shown below,

```
ENSONIT00000008797.2    GO:0000003  GO:0000149  GO:0000226
```

want to convert this file as
List

```
ENSONIT00000008797.2    GO:0000003

ENSONIT00000008797.2    GO:0000149

ENSONIT00000008797.2    GO:0000226
```

Comment: Please do add your efforts in form of code in your question, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean this? If there only one column in one line, it would not `print` anything.

```
awk '{ for(i = 2; i <= NF; i++) print $1 "\t" $i}' file
```

PS: `awk` will separate line by **space** or **tab** in default.

Tips: use `sort` and `uniq` to format the output in your requirement.